# Why my dispatch won't change the state? "Redux Toolkit"

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm practicing Redux and in my project when i dispatch an action i will see that in the dev tools but the state won't change and it will remain an empty Array. why is this happening ?
i will appreciate a little help

shopping cart.js

```js
import { createSlice, createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

// Action Creator

export const itemAdd = createAction("products/itemAdded");

const slice = createSlice({
  name: "shoppingCart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    itemAdded: (cart, action) => cart.push(action.payload),
  },
});

export const { itemAdded} = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

Dispatch

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { itemAdd } from "../../store/state/shoppingCart";

// It's an onClick Event Handler 
  const handleAddItem = (item) => {
    dispatch(itemAdd(item));
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are importing itemAdd

```
import { itemAdd } from "../../store/state/shoppingCart";
```

instead of itemAdded

```
import { itemAdded } from "../../store/state/shoppingCart";
```

Comment: Please take a look at this post. i'm soo confused why its not working                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72969744/why-filter-method-in-my-reducer-returns-an-array-of-proxy-redux-toolkit

Answer (score 1):

Also, your reducer needs braces.

```js
    itemAdded: (cart, action) => { cart.push(action.payload) }
```

Otherwise it will return the return value of `cart.push`, which is the new length of the array - and `immer` can't do its work if you modify the state and return something unrelated at the same time.