# Why filter method in my reducer returns an array of proxy? -Redux Toolkit

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

so i want to delete an item from array, `onClick` but when i log the filtered data in the console i get an array of Proxy.
i tried Changing my code but nothing worked
whats wrong here in `itemRemoved`?

```js
import { createSlice, createAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
// Action Creater
const slice = createSlice({
  name: "shoppingCart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    itemAdded: some code // ,
    itemRemoved: (cart, { payload }) => {
      cart.filter((item) => {
        if (item.id === payload.id) {
            if (item.count === 1) {
                return cart.filter((item) => item.id !== payload.id);
            } 
            else {
                const itemIndex = cart.indexOf(item);
                cart[itemIndex].count = cart[itemIndex].count - 1;
                return cart;
            }
        }
      });
    },
  },
});
export const { itemAdded, itemRemoved } = slice.actions;
export default slice.reducer;
```

Comment: see first of all try to give me a sense of what are you really doing here, second post the code of the component from which you are dispatching the action, in itemRemoved what are you actually returning, I cant see that you are returning anything, what you are returning inside cart.filter() is a part of filter(). You have made it too complex

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why reducer function return only proxy? redux/toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65764486/why-reducer-function-return-only-proxy-redux-toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to remove the element with the id you are passing through the dispatch function

```
itemRemoved: (state, { payload }) => {
       const newCart = state.cart.filter(item => item.id !== payload.id)
       const state.cart = newCart
       return state
}),
```